# appcompat for a project imported from eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, material-design

I imported a project from Eclipse where I had no problem. After migrating to android studio 1.0.2, it tells me to do some changes because of appcompat-v7 (for example in the menus I should not use android:ShowAsIcon etc...).

I have 1 MainActivity (extends Activity) which is a container to fragments and several fragments that are visible when relevant.

If I understand correctly, appcompat-v7 gives me the option to use the new design styles of API21 (like elevation for example) even on API 15 (which is my minSDK)?

Should MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity instead of Activity just because of appcompat-v7? I'm a bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

```
If I understand correctly, appcompat-v7 gives me the option to use the new 
design styles of API21 (like elevation for example)
```

The appcompat21 allows you to support material design on Pre-Lollipop Devices. But it doesn't support the elevation on older devices.

You can start from this [doc](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

```
Should MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity instead of Activity...
```

Yes.To apply the appCompat style you have to extend the ActionBarActivity.

```
(for example in the menus I should not use android:ShowAsIcon etc...).
```

Use app:showAsIcon.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```